# How to move a file in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to move a file to documents directory after I choose the file by using UIDocumentPickerViewController.

I don't see any error, but the file doesn't move to the directory.

I'd like to know how can I move the file.

```
class MyClassController: UIViewController,UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

 var thisURL:URL?   

  @IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {


    let add = UIAlertAction(title: "add", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in                         
          do {

            let myURL = URL(string:"\(self.thisURL!)")!


                   let path = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)


                let MyDesPath = path.appendingPathComponent(myURL.lastPathComponent)

                            print(path)
                                do {
                                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: “\(MyDesPath)") == false {
                                                                           try  FileManager.default.moveItem(at: myURL, to: URL(string:”\(MyDesPath)")!)

                                                                       }
                                                                       else {

                                                                       }
                                                                      }
                                                                        catch let error {
                                                                         print(error)
                                                                     }

                                                                           }

                                                                     catch let error{
                                                                         print(error)
                                                                         return
                                                                     }

    })
 func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
     NSLog("documentPicker executed")
    thisURL = urls[0]

    self.fileName.text = "\(thisURL!.lastPathComponent)"


    }
 }
```

Comment: *I don't see any error,* Apparently (because of the weird indentation) the code doesn't even compile

Comment: To allow people to answer your query, please format your code to make it readable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have done the same thing earlier, Please refer below steps and code:

1. Create a file URL to the temporary folder

   ```
    var tempURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
   ```
2. Append filename and extension to URL

   ```
    tempURL.appendPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
   ```
3. If the file with the same name exists remove it (replace a file with the new one)

## Full Code:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    let newUrls = urls.flatMap { (url: URL) -> URL? in

        var tempURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())          
        tempURL.appendPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
        do {

            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: tempURL.path) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: tempURL.path)
            }
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: url.path, toPath: tempURL.path)
            return tempURL
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Full credit to @COVID19 for the answer though in my case using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` put the file in the temp folder already and some may like to place it in the documents directory. This is a way of going about that with a single file being selected.

```
        guard let url = urls.first else { return }

        var newURL = FileManager.getDocumentsDirectory()
        newURL.appendPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
        do {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: newURL.path) {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: newURL.path)
        }
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: url.path, toPath: newURL.path)
            print("The new URL: \(newURL)")
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

and my handy helper method

```
extension FileManager {

   static func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
       let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
       let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
       return documentsDirectory
   }
}
```